# "may be used uninitialized in this function" how to remove this warning?

Tags: c, stm32

I'm going to separate my data using strtok "#", the data is like "157#178#666#..." -ish. I know there is another way to parse it, but i dont know how. this is my code

```
HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, (uint8_t*)dataB,77);

  char *delim="A";
    char *b,*c,*d,*e,*f,*g,*h,*i,*j,*k,*l,*m,*n,*o,*p,*q,*r,*s;
    char *sampah =dataB;
    char *a=strtok(sampah,delim);

    if (a != NULL) {
      b = strtok(NULL, delim);
      if (b != NULL) {
        c = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if (c != NULL) {
          d = strtok(NULL, delim);
          if (d != NULL) {
            e = strtok(NULL, delim);
            if (e != NULL) {
              f = strtok(NULL, delim);
              if (f != NULL) {
                g = strtok(NULL, delim);
                if (g != NULL) {
                  h = strtok(NULL, delim);
                  if (h != NULL) {
                    i = strtok(NULL, delim);
                    if (i != NULL) {
                      j = strtok(NULL, delim);
                      if (j != NULL) {
                        k = strtok(NULL, delim);
                        if (k != NULL) {
                          l = strtok(NULL, delim);
                          if (l != NULL) {
                            m = strtok(NULL, delim);
                            if (m != NULL) {
                              n = strtok(NULL, delim);
                              if (n != NULL) {
                                o = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                if (o != NULL) {
                                  p = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                  if (p != NULL) {
                                    q = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                    if (q != NULL) {
                                      r = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                      if (r != NULL) {
                                        s = strtok(NULL, delim);
                                      }
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

when i use b, it says '*b' may be used uninitialized in this function

can someone help me with this?

Comment: Just going by your title: *""may be used uninitialized in this function" how to remove this warning?"* -- isn't the obvious answer either not using the thing or initializing it? What do you find unclear about this error message? *(For example, you might expand your question by explaining why you think the thing is initialized before it is used. Or whatever counter you can give to the compiler's complaint.)*

Comment: As a general tip, whenever you find yourself needing a large number of variables that all get used in similar ways, they should probably be an array instead.  You could reduce the whole thing to a single very short loop.

Comment: Remove the C++ tag, this is clearly "C"

Comment: `char *b` is **declared**, but the string pointed to by `sampah` _may_ mean that `b` is never assigned a value... You could change it to `char *b = NULL, *c = NULL, ...` or use a loop and an array of pointers...

Comment: The warning should include a line number - is that line actually part of the code you showed us?  I'll bet there is some later part of the function where you use `b` and the others. In general, code questions need to include a [mcve]; that means **all** the code needed to reproduce the problem, not just a snippet or a guess as to which part is relevant.

Comment: It's fantastic when people correctly indent code. _But_ if you need to indent this much, you may want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Questions for debugging help should have a [mre]. One of the things this means is that you should attempt to reproduce the error, not demonstrate "separate my data using strtok". As part of that, you should eliminate what is not needed to produce the error, such as variables `c` through `s`.

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to convert these to integers, you could consider avoiding `strtok` completely, and use `strtol`. This function can give you back a pointer to the next character after conversion, which you could test is equal to `#` or end-of-string. All the advice about doing this in a loop to avoid code repetition still applies.

Comment: The warning is not from the posted code.

Comment: Also in case that's the DMA buffer then this is some very problematic code. You'd need to finish in time before more data appears  - that is, you need a realtime spec with a maximum allowed baudrate.

Answer (score 6):

The warning you're getting about `*b` being potentially uninitialized is due to the nested structure of your `if` statements, which might lead to not all variables (`b`, `c`, `d`, ...) being assigned values if some conditions are not met. This can happen when `strtok` returns `NULL`, and the subsequent variables are not assigned any value.

A more clean way to achieve what you want is to declare an array of pointers and iterate through them using a loop, something like this;

```cpp
    char *delim = "#";
    char *tokens[20];  // adjust the size as needed

    char *token = strtok(dataB, delim);
    int tokenCount = 0;

    while (token != NULL && tokenCount < 20) {
        tokens[tokenCount] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        tokenCount++;
    }
    // Now tokens[0] contains "157", tokens[1] contains "178", and so on...
```

Comment: I think for now my goal is to simplify the code, and thank you for the answer. I will make a question again about this in the different section